# jquery datepicker is not working in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-datepicker

the jquery datepicker is not working. I don't know why. Everyone is doing the same thing, same code, but mine is not working. Can anybody tell where is my problem, my code is given below --

Javascript:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#dtpStartDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/MM/yy" });
    });
</script>
```

html Code in view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="text-left">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="text-left">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @id = "dtpStartDate" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Does not work" is very vague. What is the expected behaviour?What is the current behaviour/error?

Comment: Works fine here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpACZ/1/).

Comment: MiniRagnarok, I also expect to be worked fine, but unexpectedly it isn't.

Comment: rivarolle, does not work mean, the calendar is not popping.

Comment: install Firebug on your Firefox and see what errors you get int there.

Comment: We would need to see a whole lot more code.  1. Firebug as suggested. 2. Are you using another javascript library like EXT or Prototype etc...  $ conflict ?   We all expect that jquery is not loading or an error is occurring.

Comment: Firefox error console says that $('#dtpStartDate').datepicker is not a function!!!!!

Comment: @Tom Stickel, I am not using other jquery library. But I again tried with jQuery.noConflict() and the result is same.

Comment: Just one thing, I am using Twitter Bootstrap. Can that be a problem???

Comment: Oh, at last I got the solution. I was using bootstrap and the jquery.js was declared at the end of the _layout page. I just move that at the top and the problem is solved :) Thanks guys for being with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding the jquery.js at the top is the key of the solution, this thing was placed at the bottom of the _layout page. The new sequence is -

> script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.js")" type="text/javascript">
>   script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript">
>   script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript">